# Find the sequences $a_n$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2/(2-a_n)}}<\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Question: How much slow a positive sequence $a_n$ must converge to zero in order that $$\tag{1}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2/(2-a_n)}}<\infty.$$

I alread found that $a_n=1/\log{(\log{n})}$ solve $(1)$, however, it was only by trial and error.

If my calculations are right, when one try to force the ratio test or the root test, the limit is always 1, so it is inconclusive, therefore, one must try a comparison test with another series, but I fail to see the aproppriate one.

Note that in the infinity, the series in (1) behaves like the harmonic series, so the point here is try to not get too close of the harmonic series.

Comment: Do you mean $a_n = \log \log n$?

Comment: Sorry @Alex, I have fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Also, did you try taking $e^{\frac{2}{2-a_n}\log n}$?

Comment: That's a good idea. Let me see if I can get somewhere with it. Thank you @Alex

Comment: Clearly it needs to be strictly greater than $\log n$